# Array Structure and Reformatting

Tags: php, sql, arrays

This is almost two questions in one. Firstly I have an array that is populated from an SQL table which is for a series of events to then output onto a calendar.

In the database there is a column called 'day' which will be the day of the week ('Monday', 'Tuesday' etc.)

Below is the code I have used to add dimensions to the array based on the 'day'.

```
$days = array('Monday' => array(), 'Tuesday' => array(), 'Tuesday' => array(), 'Wednesday' => array(), 'Thursday' => array(), 'Friday' => array(), 'Saturday' => array(), 'Sunday' => array());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $days[$row['day']][] = $row;
}
```

This new array is now structured as follows: $days['Monday'][0]['name']
I have then split this multidimensional array into multiple separate arrays.

```
$monday = $days['Monday']; $tuesday = $days['Tuesday']; $wednesday = $days['Wednesday']; $thursday = $days['Thursday']; $friday = $days['Friday']; $saturday = $days['Saturday']; $sunday = $days['Sunday'];
```

The array is now structured as follows:  $monday[0]['name']

1. What I really need is to remove a layer and have the structure as:
   $monday['name']. What would be the best way to achieve this?
2. Also, I've got to this point by going step-by-step as my knowledge
   of array functions is pretty patchy. There must be an easier way to
   do all of the above and slim down the code a bit, would anyone be
   able to point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your logic that you'll always only get 1 row for each day?

If so, just change

```
$days[$row['day']][] = $row;
```

into

```
$days[$row['day']] = $row;
```

in your while().

This actually means that most of what you did in your first line is redundant, and you can just change it into `$days = array();`